# How to add one and more leaves in jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I add leave in datepicker using array but, two leave is on same day is not showing in calendar only first leave in array is showing but second leave is not showing.

my var leaveday array is like this = `"2021,09,28,Love is on Leave-2021,09,18,Pravin is on Leave-2021,09,25,Darshit is on Leave-2021,09,18,Love is on Leave-"`

my jquery is here

```
var leave_dates= $("#all_past_leave").val();
if(leave_dates !== null && leave_dates !== '' && leave_dates !== undefined) {
    var leave_all = leave_dates.slice(0,-1);
    var leaveDays = leave_all.split('-');
 }
$(function() {
    $("#past_leave").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths:3,
       beforeShowDay: setLeaveDays
    });
  
    // set Leave function which is configured in beforeShowDay
   function setLeaveDays(date) {
     for (i = 0; i < leaveDays.length; i++) {
          
        var leaveData = leaveDays[i].split(',');

        if (date.getFullYear() == leaveData[0]
            && date.getMonth() == leaveData[1] - 1
            && date.getDate() == leaveData[2]) {
          return [true, 'staff_leaves', leaveData[3]];
       }
     }
    return [true, ''];
  }
  });
```

I am getting result like this [see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfSWL.png)

but I want result like this *I edited from chrome inspect for example*  [see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDD1g.png)

Comment: Just to clarify, by "leave" do you mean "holiday" (or similar)? As in "on leave"?

Comment: yah just like holidays